# Why does unicodedata.name() raise "ValueError: no such name" for some ASCII characters?

Tags: python, unicode

`unicodedata.name('\x00')` raises a `ValueError` exception:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('\x00')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
```

`\x00` is the NUL character. Why does `unicodedata.name('\x00')` raise an exception? I am getting the same error for other non-printable ASCII characters (`\x00` to `\x1F`, and `\x7F`). Is `unicodedata.name()` only for printable characters? If so, where is it mentioned in the Python documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_Unicode), `Cc` control characters have no name in Unicode. All the characters you mentioned are categorized under `Cc` category(You can confirm this by using `unicodedata.category` API)

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category('\x00')
'Cc'
>>> unicodedata.category('\x1F')
'Cc'
>>> unicodedata.category('\x7F')
'Cc'
```

> In Unicode, "Control-characters" are U+0000—U+001F (C0 controls),
> U+007F (delete), and U+0080—U+009F (C1 controls). Their General
> Category is "Cc". Formatting codes are distinct, in General Category
> "Cf". **The `Cc` control characters have no Name in Unicod**e, but are given
> labels such as `"<control-001A>"` instead.

You can also see [*CONTROL CHARACTER*s are](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Tools/unicode/genwincodec.py#L20) explicitly handled in [cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Tools/unicode/genwincodec.py#L35)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what the name of a unicode character means, it refers to this list: https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/NamesList.txt

As you can read, all the non-printable ASCII control characters are named "`<control>`": "`NULL`" is not the name of 0000, it's an alias.

Now, why doesn't Python display "`<control>`" is another question that I can't answer.

Comment: I think it is because '<control>' is not unique, and so it could cause other problems.